# Creating a dynamic table from dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

First of all I'm using ms SQL server 2012. I' trying to use a table based on a string value passed in as a string into a procedure. I found out that you can't use strings are table names when writing a query so I'm trying to find a way around that. The only lead I'm kind of onto is using dynamic SQL which I also am not sure how to make work. Here is what I have:

```
DECLARE @q AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @q = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @tableName
DECLARE #tableCopy AS EXECUTE(@q)
```

How can I get the executed @q into #tableCopy? Or is there a better way to access my table when all I know is the tables name as a string?

Comment: @HLGEM I need to use a table where one of the stored values is a JSON. From that I need to create a temporary table to view the JSON values as a table along with the rest of the data. This is prototyping code but good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the temporary table and then insert into that table inside the dynamic sql. There's an example here:
http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/10/14/t-sql-using-result-of-a-dynamic-sql-query-in-a-variable-or-table/

Unfortunately, you would need to know the schema. The following does *not* work:

```
declare @query varchar(max) = 
'select * into #t from table'
EXEC(@query) 
select * FROM #t
```

Comment: Thank you sir you have showed me the way of dynamic sql and I will not forget it.